# Error with django-geoposition/json-response

Tags: django, django-geoposition

I'm doing an autocomplete input.

I'm trying to create a json response.
In my model I have this:

```
   position = GeopositionField(default=DEFAULT)
```

When I try to create the json response gives me this error:

```
   TypeError: Geoposition(40,2) is not JSON serializable
```

How could I fix this ?

**Edit 1:**

In `views.py`:

```
data =[{'label': n.nombre, 'nombre': n.nombre, 'posicion': n.position, 'status': n.estado} for n in
               Dispositivo.objects.filter(nombre__icontains=what)]

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: How are you creating the response?

Comment: @che I edit the question. Look now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is pretty much the what the exception says. GeopositionField is a complex type, which does not have any standard way of serializing to JSON. You have to split it up into individual coordinates, for example by convertion it to a dictionary in your model.

Like this:

```
class Dispositivo(models.Model):
    ...

    def position_dict(self):
        return {'lat': self.position.latitude, 'lon': self.position.longitude}
```

And then in data you're dumping, write `{... 'position': n.position_dict(), ...}` to use the dictionary representation instead of the complex field.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Now, how can I serialize a decimal?I tried `Decimal(n.position.latitude)` in data and didn't work.I could to serialize converting to a string `str(n.position.latitude)`

Comment: How can I use `position_dict` in a query like that: `a=Dispositivo.objects.filter(bla='bla').values(...,position_dict.lat,position_dict.lon)`

Comment: @Don: I don't think you can.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem just by putting CharField when serializer on GeopositionField

on serializers.py put this:

```
position = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
```